# Woocommerce - override wc_create_new_customer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

It's look like impossible to override this function. I'm trying to send the created user id, mail and password to another database so I added this hook :

```
function ex_create_new_customer( $email, $username = '', $password = '' ) {

    // add to datastory BD

    /* GenSalt */

    $string = str_shuffle(mt_rand());
    $salt   = uniqid($string ,true);

    $rounds = 12;

    $crypted_password = crypt($_POST['password'], '$2y$'. $rounds . '$' . $salt);

    /*request sql*/
    $servername = "server_address";
    $username = "my_user";
    $passworddb = "user_pass_for_db";
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=db_name", $username, $passworddb);


    try {
        $conn->exec("INSERT INTO user(user_nom, user_prenom, user_mdp, user_mail ) VALUES('".$_POST['billing_last_name']."', '".$_POST['billing_first_name']."', '".$crypted_password."', '0', '".$_POST['email']."')");
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die( $e->getMessage() );
    }

}

add_action( 'wc_create_new_customer', 'ex_create_new_customerZ', 1 , 3 );
```

Even changing the function name to `ex_create_new_customerZ` doesn't trigger an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it's not the right hook to use. `wc_create_new_customer` is a function not an action.

In your case, you can use the action `woocommerce _created_customer` which is trigger right after the `wp_insert_user` in the `wc_create_new_customer`. [More details](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_create_new_customer.html#37-117)

```
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'ex_create_ new_customer', 99, 3);
```

Note that `wc_create_new_customer` function can be override if you declare a new function with the same name (the function is between `function_exists` statement). In this case you'll need to add both WC code and your own code.

Comment: Thank you the `add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'ex_create_ new_customer', 99, 3);`works

Comment: You maybe notice that there is one filter that you can use if you want some datas from your remote server to be add with the wp_insert_user séquence.